# Criteria Builder and sub select query in from

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

Is it possible to convert the following SQL query to criteria builder?

```
SELECT k.id,
       k.id2,
       k.name
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          id2,
          name
   FROM table1
   JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.tab1_id) as k
```

NOTE: The query itself is not important what matters is a sub select after `FROM` keyword.

I see that criteriaQuery.from() has a signature which allows only

```
<X> Root<X> from(Class<X> entityClass);
<X> Root<X> from(EntityType<X> entity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing through docs I found out that that is not possible and need to go around by creating extra queries and / or extra tables.